# What is the most accurate and accepted philosophy of perception in 21st century?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, perception

*The philosophy of perception is concerned with the nature of perceptual experience and the status of perceptual data, in particular how they relate to beliefs about, or knowledge of, the world.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_perception

I am wondering which is the most accepted philosophical approach within the developments in science and philosophy in 21st century?

Comment: I bet on constructivism, even that it is from the 18th century, see Kant's Critique of Pure Reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What one can be most certain of is one's own assessment of one's own experience.  Direct experience can be fooled, e.g. optical illusions, but a closer analysis reveals the truth, as close as one can get to it at any moment.

Kant's 18th century fusion of Hume's empiricism and Leibniz's rationalism laid the solid foundation for analysing experience.  However his Critique of Pure Reason could only establish one's own existence and relation to things in the world.  To encompass the reality of other people for his moral philosophy he had to assume their validity, hence his Critique of *Practical* Reason.

If one stays with pure reason, Kant is the modern successor to Descartes.  Kant's view on the existence of things is expressed in [The Critique of Pure Reason A598/B626](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4280/pg4280-images.html#linknote-67) (at page centre):

> Being is evidently not a real predicate, that is, a conception of
> something which is added to the conception of some other thing. It is
> merely the positing of a thing, or of certain determinations in it.
> Logically, it is merely the copula of a judgement.

The judgement of a cogito on the copula [concept + predicates] of a thing makes its existence, which, in multiplicity, constitute the perceived things in perception, memory and understanding.

Heidegger refined and extended Kant's ideas about the source of experience, but the existential basis of the perceived world remains Kantian (as transcendental idealism).

Exactly how the cogito reifies a thing is complex because before a judgement can be made the cogito has to vaguely recognise something is there.  So there is an unconscious recognition or rationalisation before conscious judgement makes its formal determination.  Neuroscience has observed this pre-conscious activity in MRI scans.  Pure reason hits its limit at the threshold of the unconscious.  Beyond that there are lots of interesting theories but there is a difference between the certain and the theoretical.

Comment: The Abhidharma has a lot to say about the phenomenology of perception, well worth studying.